# Is SPWebCollection.Add method asynchronous?

Tags: 2013

I am adding a new web and then trying to break inheritance and add groups permission but it says object still inherits.

I want to know that is this method sync or async ?

Comment: It should be synchronous as it returns an SPWeb object. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SPWebCollection.Add` calls a method named `CreateWeb`. That method is synchronous and is as follows:

```
private SPWeb CreateWeb(string strUrl, string strTitle, string strDescription, uint nLCID, string strWebTemplate, bool bCreateUniqueSubweb, bool bConvertIfThere, Guid webId, Guid rootFolderId, bool createSystemCatalogs, Guid appInstanceId, string appWebDomainId)
{
  SPGlobal.ValidateWebName(strUrl, true);
  if (!this.IsValidWebUrl(strUrl))
  {
    throw new ArgumentException(SPResource.GetString("InvalidUrl", (object) strUrl));
  }
  else
  {
    if (strUrl.StartsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
      string strPrefix = strUrl.Substring(1);
      if (this.WebApplication.Prefixes.Contains(strPrefix) || this.WebApplication.WebService.HostHeaderPrefixes.Contains(strPrefix))
        throw new SPException(SPResource.GetString("ContainsReservedName", (object) strPrefix));
    }
    bool allowUnsafeUpdates = this.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
    string str = this.MakeFullUrl(strUrl);
    SPRequest spRequest = this.GetSPRequest();
    spRequest.SetIgnoreCanary(allowUnsafeUpdates);
    using (new SPSecurity.GrantAdditionalPermissionsInScope(SPBasePermissions.AddAndCustomizePages))
      spRequest.CreateWeb(str, strTitle, strDescription, nLCID, bCreateUniqueSubweb, ref appInstanceId, appWebDomainId, bConvertIfThere, ref webId, ref rootFolderId, createSystemCatalogs);
    SPWeb spWeb = new SPWeb(this, str, true, spRequest);
    this.RemoveDuplicateOpenedWebs(spWeb);
    spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafeUpdates;
    Guid id = spWeb.ID;
    try
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strWebTemplate))
        spWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(strWebTemplate);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      SPWeb.HandleWebCreationException(str, spWeb, ex);
      throw;
    }
    finally
    {
      spWeb.Close();
      spWeb = (SPWeb) null;
      SPRequestManager.Instance.Release(spRequest);
    }
    SPWeb web = this.OpenWeb(id);
    try
    {
      web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafeUpdates;
      SPWeb parentWeb = web.ParentWeb;
      using (new SPSecurity.GrantAdditionalPermissionsInScope(SPBasePermissions.AddAndCustomizePages))
        SPWeb.CopyPropertiesFromParentWebToWeb(parentWeb, web, bCreateUniqueSubweb);
      parentWeb.Close();
      ULS.SendTraceTag(1975265U, (ULSCatBase) ULSCat.msoulscat_WSS_General, ULSTraceLevel.Verbose, "Site and root web created at {0}. Setting NeedsUpgrade=false for the rootweb", (object) str);
      if (web.Site.CompatibilityLevel < 15)
        SPManager.Instance.NeedsUpgradeFalsePreviousVersion((object) web);
      else
        SPManager.Instance.NeedsUpgradeFalse((object) web);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      SPWeb.HandleWebCreationException(str, spWeb, ex);
      throw;
    }
    return web;
  }
}
```

You are probably missing an Update somewhere after braking the inheritance or after adding the groups.

Comment: how did you find this code, I tried JetBrains for looking into Microsoft.SharePoint assembly, but that search ended in SPWebCOllection.cs class, where is this code residing, + 1

Comment: by the way,you don't need to update web after adding groups to it.

Comment: SPWebCollection.Add is in Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection and CreateWeb is in Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.SPWebCollectionProvider.